# What's wrong in this SELECT query?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, t-sql, ado.net

```
Dim cmdSelect As New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [seat_remain] FROM [a1_ticket] WHERE serv_code =" & lab5.Text & "ORDER BY [Ticket_no] DESC", SQLData)
```

Comment: Beside that it is both, a VB.NET snippet and an SQL query, I guess that it is not SQL-injection-safe. http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Comment: What are you **expecting** it to do?? What does it **actually** do??

Answer (score 8):

You are using string concatenation for constructing your SQL query instead of parametrized queries or stored procedures. That's what is wrong with it. Here's how to improve it:

```
Dim cmdSelect As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [seat_remain] FROM [a1_ticket] WHERE serv_code = @serv_code ORDER BY [Ticket_no] DESC", SQLData)
cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serv_code", lab5.Text)
```

Now your query will work and not only this but it is safe against SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

Missing quote :

```
Dim cmdSelect As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [seat_remain] FROM [a1_ticket] WHERE serv_code ='" & lab5.Text & "' ORDER BY [Ticket_no] DESC", SQLData)
```

Comment: I guess, `serv_code` could very well be an integer, so no quotes required.

Comment: @Uwe Keim: It would certainly have needed the space that Scorpi0 added in, even if not the quotes.

Comment: I guess it's a quote problem, but in fact, maybe it is the space missing too. Didn't even notice that :p